# Does Eclipse debugger support save/restore or checkpoint/rewind?

Tags: java, debugging

What I mean is the following, illustrated via an example:

I start my Java application (which happens to be a simulator). The application runs for 1 hour and fails. I want to relaunch my application in debug mode, run it to minute 59, then start stepping through the code. At any point, I want to get back to the state that was present in minute 59 and re-start my debug.

Does Eclipse or some plugin have such support? If not, is there another open source application that can be used?

This can be accomplished by using a VM and simply saving state at the point of interest. But I'm wondering if there is a more native/faster Java solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution to do this in Java that I know is this debugger from Chronon http://www.chrononsystems.com/ which integrates with Eclipse IDE.

The idea is that you record a debugging session which let you playback it. Although this is non-opensource and licensed software, it's still a cool product.

Comment: There are a couple other paid options available that I saw when googling.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a virtual maschine and taking a snapshot at the desired debugging state. You can then apply this snapshot over and over again, though this solution takes a considerably amount of time.

Comment: Could you explicit your solution a bit ? Are you talking about the *Java Virtual Machine* or a regular virtual machine with everything it contains ? And how exactly would you do it ? Thanks