# Eclipse: Save program state for debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a few things that I'm debugging in my Java program, and a few bugs that I need to work out. However, it takes a lot of setup to get to the parts I want to test. Naturally, it's getting a little frustrating to have to keep clicking through menus over and over every time I restart the program to see if my last change finally fixed the bug. I'm spending more time getting to the problem parts than I am fixing them.

Is there any way to save the state of the program in memory at any particular moment so that if I encounter a bug at a certain point in execution, I can instantly end up at that point next time I load the program? Basically, I'm thinking of how save states work in emulators, but with a java program in execution, for debugging purposes.

If this isn't a feature in Eclipse that I've missed, is there a plugin or program that can do this for me? If they aren't free, feel free to mention them for anyone else who comes across this answer in the future, but if at all possible I need something free.

Comment: I think this post can help you with your problem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12120723/3577898